# Creating a gem with associated Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, associations

I would like to package a gem that includes ActiveRecord models that can be associated with models in the existing Rails application. I've been trying to follow the code for acts_as_taggable_on, but I'm running into some problems getting the associations to work.

My gem is called Kitchen. My model defined in the gem is Dish, and I want to add a polymorphic association (as Cook) to a model in the main application such as User.

In `lib/kitchen.rb`

```
require "active_record"
require "kitchen/dish.rb"
require "kitchen/cook.rb"
```

In `lib/kitchen/dish.rb`

```
module Kitchen
  class Dish < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cook, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

In `lib/kitchen/cook.rb` (lifting code from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts_as-method-to-active-record without much understanding)

```
module Kitchen
  module Cook
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_cook
        class_eval do
          has_many :dishes, :as => :cook
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Kitchen::Cook
```

Finally, I've migrated everything in my dummy app, and include the association in `spec/dummy/app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_cook
end
```

I'm getting an error any time I try to access `user.dishes` for a User instance:

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::Dish
```

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this maybe:

```
has_many :dishes, :as => :cook, :class_name => 'Kitchen::Dish'
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed the error. Now it's giving me an error when I try to do anything with `user.dishes` 

    NoMethodError: undefined method X for Kitchen::Cook:Module

Comment: Nevermind, I just got confused translating back from the toy domain. Your answer totally works.